# Что такое супер-рекурсивный алгоритм?

Tags: алгоритм

Что такое супер-рекурсивный алгоритм (Super-recursive algorithm)? Если можно попроще и на пальцах :)
В идеале с примером.

Comment: аж самому стало интересно - вот статья https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super-recursive_algorithm
кароче, он супер ))

Comment: Видел это и [это](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25942094/what-is-a-super-recursive-algorithm) , но хотелось бы немного попонятней чем там написано :)